# getServerSession return null in API folder when requesting from server components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am currently using Next.js 13 experimental along with NextAuth Google and Prisma in the experimental **/app** folder. I have created an API in **/app/api/user/request** and am trying to make a GET request. However, when the request is made from a server page or server component, **getServerSession** returns **null** inside the endpoint. Interestingly, if the request is made from a client ('use client') component, it works fine.

I have searched for solutions and found a discussion on Github, but it appears that no one has solved this problem yet. I am wondering if anyone has encountered this issue before and if there is a solution or workaround for it.

Below is the code snippet for my NextAuth Google provider with Prisma adapter and API endpoint inside of /app/api/user/request where getServerSession returns null.
Google Provider setup with Prisma adapter[image]

API endpoint (/app/api/user/request)
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.[image]

I tried to find a solutions in the internet but it did not work for me

Comment: i suggest you to grab a postman and hit these APIs and see what happens, I don't think it matters client or server, because API layer is server thing. So first make sure these calls are working from a browser level, such as postman

Comment: API is working. I just want get this session from getServerSession() as I get it from client components when making request. Maybe i messed up something. maybe I messed up somethign with auth config

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't paste screenshots of code. Paste the actual code. See the "Syntax highlighting for code" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting It will make it searchable and let many other engineers help you faster.